# Create simple GUI to open text file and read then output specific keyword

Tags: python

May i know how do we create a simple gui use to open text file then we read text file to find a keyword and display out the keyword we found in the gui? By using tkinter in pycharm.

This is the sample coding of mine to search an specific word from text file withouht using tkinter in pycharm,

```
with open("gdp.txt") and open("dummy_set_1.txt") and open ("dummy_set_3.txt") as f:
    s= f.readlines()
    for x in s:
        if x.__contains__("STATE"):
            start = x.find("STATE = ") + len("STATE']")
            end = x.find("}")
            substring = x[start:end] + " - "

            substring = x

            print(substring)
            if substring.__contains__("0x0"):
                print("0x0 found in")
```

Comment: https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-open-file-dialog/